# FullCalendar date with border affecting other dates that supposed to not have border

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fullcalendar

I have a calendar rendered using FullCalendar. I added a border for some dates - example, holidays. But in Google Chrome, it appears that some dates - which supposed to not have border appears to have broken borders. Anyone experience the same problem?

[image]

```
 var holidays = [{"title":"Special Holiday","start":"2017-10-31","holiday":"1"},{"title":"All Saints Day","start":"2017-11-01","holiday":"1"},{"title":"All Souls Day","start":"2017-11-02","holiday":"1"},{"title":"Christmas Day","start":"2017-12-25","holiday":"1"}]

$('#booking_calendar_1').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    locale: 'ja',
    theme: true,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next',
        right: ''
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    eventRender: function (event,element,view){
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');

        if (event.holiday == '1') {
            var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

            $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']')
                            .addClass('holiday');
            $(view.el[0]).find('thead .fc-day-top[data-date=' + dateString + ']')
                             .addClass('red-label');
            element.removeAttr('href');
        }
    }
});

$('#booking_calendar_1').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', holidays );
```

CSS for the dates that have red-label class

```
.calendar thead .fc-day-top.red-label .fc-day-number{
    border: 2px solid #f61320;
    color:  #f61320;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: @ShadowFiend I updated the question and pasted in some codes.. thank you..

Comment: I tried copying the code into an editor before and couldn't see any borders. Could you add a JS Fiddle example with the issue?

Comment: i think, maybe, just browser cache.. because right now, I did not update the code but the border is not there.. The issue comes and goes.. The issue is not present in firefox also.. thanks for your help guys..

Comment: I've voted to close this question, as "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced" are considered off-topic, [according to the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).